# How to close bootstrap dropdown menu on button click?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown menu that I open and got it staying open while I work with a grid that I placed inside of it, I can close the dropdown when I click outside of the dropdown area, but I want to close it down on a button click event..

Here is my html for the dropdown

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle col-md-3" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Select Category
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu col-md-7" onClick="event.stopPropagation();">
        <div id="MaterialGridList" style="height:440px;"></div>
        <button type="button" id="btnFilter" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Filter</button>
    </ul>
</div>
```

as you can see on the onClick event of the dropdown menu, it keeps it open. So what I would like to do is close it on the btnFilter click event.
Any idea's?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `toggle` function on the `.dropdown` that has the button inside:

```js
$('#btnFilter').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('button.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle col-md-3" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Select Category
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu col-md-7" onClick="event.stopPropagation();">
        <div id="MaterialGridList" style="height:440px;"></div>
        <button type="button" id="btnFilter" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Filter</button>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Just add the `data-toggle="dropdown"` tag on the elements that you want to close the menu.

```
<button type="button" id="btnFilter" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="dropdown">Filter</button>
```

Comment: This is the simplest IMO as it doesn't require any JS.

Comment: just for note you can check this links as well for complete reference 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#via-data-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your jQuery snippet of your .js file.

```
$('.nav-link').on('click',function() {
    $(".navbar-toggler-icon").trigger("click");
});
```